Is there a way to create a constraint (or attach a partition) without reading the data?
We are currenly performing a (long overdue) conversions of our database to use partitioning. The database holds a lot of timestamped records where the timestamp is indexed on it's own.
For this operation we are going to create a partitioned version of the existing tables and then attach the existing tables in as a partition of the new table.
To prevent locking while we attach the partition, we're going to create a NOT VALID constraint on the data and then validate it - as suggested in documentation:
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT partitioning_constraint 
CHECK (record_timestamp BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2024-11-20') -- Last date is several in the future
NOT VALID;

COMMIT;

ALTER TABLE foo VALIDATE CONSTRAINT partitioning_constraint; -- This is taking a very long time reading the data.

What seems strange about is that if I were to simply search for rows that do not match the constraint, the results would find no rows almost instantainiously:
SELECT * from foo WHERE record_timestamp < '2000-01-01'; -- Instantly returns no rows
SELECT * from foo WHERE record_timestamp > '2000-11-20'; -- Instantly returns no rows


We know the check constraint is valid and have proven it with simple SELECT.
The INVALID constraint proves that this is not going to change.

But we need to find a way to validate this constraint, (or attach as a partition) without reading several TB of data. This is a production instance and slamming the IO is really not an option.
Is there any way to bypass postgres re-reading many TB of data like this?

No, there is no alternative. PostgreSQL reads the whole table and verifies all rows. You could cheat by manipulating the catalog, but that's neither commendable nor supported.
If your system cannot handle a single sequential scan of the large table, what are you going to do once autovacuum starts processing it?
The constraint looks wrong, though.  A partition constraint always compares with >= on the lower end and < on the upper end, while with BETWEEN, the upper end is compared with <=.

I can't speak for what autovaccum does, it's not caused problems yet. What I do know is that AWS RDS started showing EBS IO balance dropping when testing VALIDATE against a resoted snapshot on the same instance type. We can circumvent it my switching away from a burstable instance but that's downtime we don't want.

Out of interest is there a documented reason why the validation can't make use of the indexes?

I don't think that there is a documented reason.
